# How to do this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to transform this code from JavaScript into jQuery.

This is the current code:

```
var i = 0;
    var start = true;

    document.getElementById("startclick").addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (start) {
            start = false;
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                i++;
                document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "albastru_" + i + '<br>' ;
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            start = true;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    });
```

Here is my attempt:

```
$x = 0; 
$start = true; 
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#buton2').on('click',function () { 
     if($start){ 
       $start = false; 
       $interval = setInterval(function () { 
          $x ++; 
          $('#list').html('<p>albastru_</p>' + $x + '<br>'); }, 1000); 
       } else { 
          $start = true; 
          clearInterval($interval); 
       } 
   }) 
});
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a free code conversion service and the conversion is quite simple

Comment: $x = 0;
$start = true;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buton2').on('click',function () {
        if($start){
            $start = false;
            $interval = setInterval(function () {
                $x ++;
                $('#list').html('<p>albastru_</p>' + $x + '<br>');

            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $start = true;
            clearInterval($interval);
        }
    })
});

Comment: @charlietfl i`m new to jQuery and programming,sry.And i dont know why it paste it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below. I'm assuming `startclick` is a button, after you click it `.append()` will add the required data to `#list` div after 3 seconds.

Updated Answer with start and stop buttons.

```js
var i = 0;
var start = true;
var interval = null;

$('#startclick').click(function() {
  if (interval !== null) return;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      $('#list').append("albastru_" + i + '<br>');
  }, 3000);  
});

$("#stop").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list">
</div>
<br />
<button id="startclick">START!</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
```

Comment: ,thank you for answer.But i also want when i click on start again,loop stop.

Comment: is possible to stop from the same button?

Comment: @Alex Yes, you have the code above, play around with it.